# Non-unicode characters shown as question marks on windows 7 64-bit

Tags: c++, windows-7, mfc, windows-7-x64

I have a multi language MFC application that stores localization data in string tables stored in DLLs. When I run the application in my native language (Persian) on windows 7 32-bit everything works fine and string are shown appropriately. However on windows 7 64-bit all the text is turned into question marks.
I have set the appropriate value for system locale. To my knowledge there's no difference between two systems other than 64, 32-bit.

**EDIT:**

- I tried changing the font to Tahoma and it didn't work. However
  inspecting the differences in 64-bit and 32-bit I noticed they both
  used the same `Segoe UI` font and as said before 32-bit version runs
  without a problem.
- Also I can type and search and name folder in Persian without a
  problem, it is only the application that has the problem.

Comment: 64 bit os has the language support ?

Comment: @JerryYYRain Yes, of course.

Comment: All the text, or only console output?

Comment: @rubenvb There is no console output. It's an MFC app, it's got UI and all the text in lables, textboxes, messagesboxes, etc... is shown as question marks.

Comment: Clearly the font used doesn't support the language of choice. May want to try a different font, or check if you need an extra language pack or something like that. [ALso, I believe MS doesn't sell their product in Iran, so Persian language support may not be "high" on their list of things to do...] (Sorry for the lack of very direct help)

Comment: @MatsPetersson That was my first guess too (after reading the related questions), so I changed the fonts to Tahoma-which I'm pretty sure supports Persian?- but it still doesn't work. I also checked the font setting in both 32-bit and 64-bit, they both used the same font: `Segoe UI` so I thought if this was the problem it should not have worked in any of them.

Comment: Not really sure I can offer much more help. Looks like there is a "language pack" for Persian tho', judging from here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win7

Comment: It is not a font problem, missing glyphs are displayed as rectangles, not question marks.  This is a text encoding problem, you are using characters that have no representation in the system code page.  Still relying on code pages is very unproductive, MFC will also soon stop supporting them.  Rebuild your project with UNICODE in effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was not a matter of 64/32-bit difference.
In addition to changing the system locale, I had to change the `Region and Language>Formats>Format` to Persian. I don't know how character encoding is related to date/time format but that's how it worked.

Comment: From XP (maybe 2000), Windows has had the capacity to run Ansi (Multibyte) apps as if they were Unicode for a specific language. This is why changing the region causes the app to work. As Hans Passant stated, the 'correct' solution is to compile the app for Unicode so that it will work for all regions and languages.

Comment: @user1793036 Yes I'm aware of that, but I thought changing the locale (Quoting Windows:`This setting controls the language used when displaying text in programs that do not support Unicode.`) would be sufficient. I don't see the connection between non-Unicode and date/time formatting however. I read Hans's comment and although it is correct it would be my last option. The application read/writes to files in many places, and changing from UTF-8 to Unicode will break compatibility, or at least requires a lot of effort.